# Adobe Sign API password protection not working

Tags: adobe, adobe-sign

I am uploading an agreement to Adobe Sign that needs password protection. Per https://secure.na1.adobesign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6 I should include

```
"securityOption":{
  "openPassword":"0123456789"
}
```

The separate article https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/kb/how-to-set-open-password-for-a-signed-document-using-rest-api-adobe-sign.html says the key should be `securityOptions`, but even when including both in the payload it still doesn't seem to take. Here is the full payload with excessive options filled in:

```
{
   "signatureType":"ESIGN",
   "state":"IN_PROCESS",
   "participantSetsInfo":[
      {
         "order":1,
         "role":"SIGNER",
         "memberInfos":[
            {
               "email":"xxx@xxx.xxx",
               "securityOption":{
                  "openPassword":"XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "protectOpen":true
               },
               "securityOptions":{
                  "openPassword":"XXXXXXXXXX",
                  "protectOpen":true
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "signatureFlow":"SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED",
   "fileInfos":[
      {
         "transientDocumentId":"XXXXXXXXXX"
      }
   ],
   "name":"Passworded Agreement",
   "securityOption":{
      "openPassword":"XXXXXXXXXX",
      "protectOpen":true
   },
   "securityOptions":{
      "openPassword":"XXXXXXXXXX",
      "protectOpen":true
   }
}
```

Where am I going wrong with the field(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different places for security to be applied to the document. The `securityOption` field at the top only protects management of the document and does not enforce a password for signers. That should be done through `participantSetsInfo` and the `securityOption` and must include `authenticationMethod` as `'PASSWORD'`. You can drop the `securityOptions` fields as well as the article is incorrect and those names are not part of the specification.